# How to fix conditional binding have optional type not 'Bool'?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, boolean

how can I solve this problem?

Ive been getting the same error in 10 different places, I have been running tests on it and can't seem to figure this

thanks in advance for any help that you guys provide it really means a lot to me

***Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'***

```
extension HomeController: FiltersViewControllerDelegate{
    func query(withCategory jewelry: Bool, shoe: Bool, hat: Bool, apearel: Bool, gear: Bool) -> Query {

        if jewelry == false && shoe == false && hat == false && apearel == false && gear == false {
            stackViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
            activeFiltersStackView.isHidden = true
        } else {
            stackViewHeightConstraint.constant = 44
            activeFiltersStackView.isHidden = false
        }

        var filtered = baseQuery

        // Sort and Filter data
        if let jewelry = jewelry, !jewelry.isEmpty {                      //Error
            filtered = filtered.whereField("category", isEqualTo: jewelry)
        }
        //......more Filters....\\

        if let gear = gear, !gear.isEmpty {                               //Error
            filtered = filtered.whereField("category", isEqualTo: gear)
        }

        return filtered
    }

    func controller(_ controller: FilterViewController,
                      didSelectCategory jewelry: Bool,
                      shoe: Bool,
                      hat: Bool,
                      apearel: Bool,
                      gear: Bool) {

        if jewelry == false && shoe == false && hat == false && apearel == false && gear == false {
            stackViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
            activeFiltersStackView.isHidden = true
        } else {
            stackViewHeightConstraint.constant = 44
            activeFiltersStackView.isHidden = false
        }

        let filtered = query(withCategory: jewelry, shoe: shoe, hat: hat, apearel: apearel, gear: gear)


        if let jewelry = jewelry, ! jewelry.isEmpty {                //Error
            jewelryFilterLbl.text = "Jewelry"
            jewelryFilterLbl.isHidden = false
        } else {
            jewelryFilterLbl.isHidden = true
        }

        //......more Filters....\\

        if let gear = gear, !gear.isEmpty {                          //Error
            gearFilterLbl.text = "gear"
            gearFilterLbl.isHidden = false
        } else {
            gearFilterLbl.isHidden = true
        }

        query = filtered
    }

}
```

Comment: check this `if jewelry  {}` instead of `if let jewelry = jewelry, ! jewelry.isEmpty {`, reason .isEmpty is not a property of a Bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.isEmpty` check it's not a property of a `Bool`

```
    if jewelry {                      //Error
        filtered = filtered.whereField("category", isEqualTo: jewelry)
    }
    //......more Filters....\\

    if gear {                               //Error
        filtered = filtered.whereField("category", isEqualTo: gear)
    }
```

Comment: what the difference between `if jewelry {}` and `if jewelry == true {}`

Comment: op edited the question it was having ? check his edit

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik There's no difference.

Comment: @Roberto - ,  Sh_Khan created the condition if jewelry == true {} thats why I asked

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik if `jewelry ` was optional then we have to check it like this or raise an unwrap error like what you have edited in your above comment

Comment: running tests right now give me a few moments please

Answer (score 0):

You're using `if let` binding on variables that are not optionals.

For example, your `jewel` variable is a `Bool`, not a `Bool?`. Using optional binding doesn’t make any sense.

```swift
if let jewelry = jewelry, ! jewelry.isEmpty {  // Jewelry isn't an Optional!!!
    jewelryFilterLbl.text = "Jewelry"
    jewelryFilterLbl.isHidden = false
} else {
    jewelryFilterLbl.isHidden = true
}
```

Plus, as other users have stated, `Bool` variables don't have `.isEmpty` method. Revise your logic and your code, it doesn't work at all.